# Django Graphql middleware decode token

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

In my project I used `Django` and `GraphQl` for building API. User will be authenticated by `API Gateway` in `AWS`, and send  a `JWT token`, with uuid `username` body, included in the request headers to the backend.

I need to decode that token and get an `username` value, that will be next used in the resolvers.
I have planned to use something similar as `G` object in `Flask` or something similar using Rack [Djangos middleware](https://github.com/RenoFi/rack-graphql#example-using-context-handler-for-jwt-authentication) but I'm struggling how to do it in Django.

Do you have any idea or hint?

Comment: Did you find a good solution?

Comment: @Peterhack check the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the result which I implemented:

The middleware checks the jwt token before resolver call, based on decoded username it create a User instance, that is assigned in info.context.user parameter.
The info.context will be visible in resolver.

So basically in resolver you can check a User instance as:

```
user = info.context.user
if isinstance(user, User):
    # do something
```

```
middleware.py

class AuthorizationGraphQLMiddleware:
    """Middleware add User object for each GraphQL resolver info.context"""
    def resolve(self, next, root, info, **kwargs):
        username = None
        auth_header = info.context.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')

        if auth_header:
            username = decode_token(auth_header)['username']

        if username is not None:
            info.context.user = User(username)
        else:
            info.context.user = AnonymousUser()

        return next(root, info, **kwargs)
```

```
entities.py

@dataclass
class User:
    name: str
```

```
utils.py

class TokenValidationError(GraphQLError):
    pass

def decode_token(token):
    try:
        return jwt.decode(token.replace('Bearer ', ''), verify=False)
    except (jwt.DecodeError, AttributeError):
        raise TokenValidationError('Invalid token.')
```

```
settings.py

GRAPHENE = {
    'MIDDLEWARE': ('api.graphql.middleware.AuthorizationGraphQLMiddleware',)
}
```